# spring security 4 with weblogic is not working where as its working in tomcat

Tags: spring-security, weblogic-10.x

Developed spring rest(version 4.3.1) with spring security (version 4.1.1) basic authentication and its working fine in tomcat .its prompting username/password window when tomcat url is accessed but when same application is deployed in weblogic its not asking for authentication and all urls being accessible  with out prompting for username/password window.  i see link which has solution  but its corrupted . https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/preauth-xml . Need some inputs from expert as i need to resolve it soon. please provide ideas to resolve it. thank you